# SSRS 2017- Data Source option has disappeared from web portal

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

We have an SSRS server, and in the past, we would use the web portal to change the datasource and dataset in the sidebar menu.  However, when we logged in recently, we noticed that this functionality had disappeared from the menu (see image below). I'm not sure if this is a configuration or permissions issue causing it -- how do I get this back?[image: er]

Comment: Seeing  you don't have the `Security` option either on that menu list, I would say you don't have permissions.

Comment: WEI_DBA is that based on the user's active directory settings? the db login for SSRS -  NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices is set to sysadmin.  I'm new to SSRS so not sure where to go to configure the permissions for individual users (including myself)

Comment: SSRS / Site Settings